# How to iterate over dataframe such that all rows which have a specific column value in common are saved to their respective files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

This questions was a little harder for me to phrase so I request to help edit the question which would make more sense (if necessary).

**Problem Statement:**
I want all the rows which have a specific column value in common, saved to same file.

**Example Code**
I want to do something like this. Say, I have a dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 6, 3, 4], 'col2': [3, 4, 2, 5, 6], 'col3':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'], 'col4':['2', '3', '2', '2', '2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

I want to create csv files such that:

- all rows where `col3` is `a`, they all get saved in `a.csv` all rows
- where `col3` is `b`, they all get saved in `b.csv` all rows where
- `col3` is `c`, they all get saved in `c.csv`

**Hypothesized Solution:** The only way I can think of creating the CSV files is iterating through the dataframe per row and checking if the column (e.g. `col3` val) has a csv created already, if not -- create and add the rows or else append to exists csv file.

**Issue:**
Above sample code is just a representation. I have a very large dataframe. If it helps, I know the unique value in the column in question (like, `col3` is example) as a list somewhere. However, on of the most popular answer on  `how to iterate over a dataframe?` : [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) says (in the second answer there) that `DON'T`. I might have to use it as a last resort if there is no other way but if there is one, can someone help me get a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file (here `all.csv`) is large and you want to process csv in chunks, you can try this strategy: open a file when the first occurrence is met and save the handle into a dict. Next when you meet the same occurrence, load the handle and use it to write the data and so on.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

DIRPATH = "/tmp/csv_folder"

# create folder if it doesn't exist
dirpath = pathlib.Path(DIRPATH)
dirpath.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

# chunksize=2 for demo purpose only...
reader = pd.read_csv("all.csv", chunksize=2)
streams = {}

for df in reader:
    for grp, dfg in df.groupby("col3"):
        try:
            buffer = streams[grp]
            dfg.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False)
        except KeyError:
            # grp is met for the first time
            buffer = open(dirpath / f"{grp}.csv", "w")
            streams[grp] = buffer
            dfg.to_csv(buffer, index=False)

for fp in streams.values():
    fp.close()
```

```sh
$ cat /tmp/csv_folder/a.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,3,a,2
3,5,a,2

$ cat /tmp/csv_folder/b.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
2,4,b,3
4,6,b,2

$ cat /tmp/csv_folder/c.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
6,2,c,2
```

Comment: Thanks. May I now what are `grp` and `dfg` representing? I saw the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html but couldn't understand.

Comment: `grp` is the value of the group ("a", "b",  "c"), i.e. the unique values of `col3` (try: `df["col3"].unique()`. `dfg` is the subset dataframe of `df` where all values of `col3` is `grp` (try: `df.loc[df["col3"] == "a"]`)

Comment: Thank you! Great. Quick question. Currently files (here csv) are being stored in the same directory where the notebook is run. if I want to save all csv files in another directory which is a variable (like `/csv_folder`) how does `f"{grp}.csv"` change?

Comment: @Sulphur. I updated my answer according to your request.

Comment: I more question, please. Does this method only work when we do one pass of the dataframe and see all unique values and create CSV? I ask this because I will be working with chunks of dataframe (like here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67155322/how-to-read-chunk-from-middle-of-a-long-csv-file-using-python-200-gb).  So, in first pass one chunk (~=1000 rows) of df gets respective rows saved into respective csv file. When I do second pass (i.e. next ~1000 rows) in next iteration, do the same as above, will the values be appended to existing csv files if they exist, or will they be overwriten?

Comment: @Sulphur, try my solution to read csv in chunks.

Answer (score 2):

You can TRY:

```
vals = ['a','b','c']
for i in vals:
    df.loc[df.col3.eq(i)].to_csv(f"{i}.csv", index= False)
```

NOTE: if you wanna do this for all different values in col3, then you can use `unique`:

```
for i in df.col3.unique():
    df.loc[df.col3.eq(i)].to_csv(f"{i}.csv", index= False)
```

Comment: In my case, second will be probably more helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea
First, get the list of items in col_3.
Then, using the list, split the data and convert it to csv. I hope it does what you want it to do.

```
col_3list = list(sorted(set(df['col3'])))
for i in range(len(col_3list)):
  new_df = df[df['col3']==col_3list[i]]
  csv_writer = new_df.to_csv('data_sample'+str(i)+'.csv')
```